# RMarkdown in RStudio - is it possible to completely hide LaTeX preview

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm starting to use RMarkdown for documents with a lot of equations. RStudio has a nice feature of previewing latex when I'm writing it which I like, however after I've written the equation I don't need it taking up space in my text editor area, see image:

[image]

There is the option to "hide it" by clicking the two arrows in the corner of the preview but even after this it still takes up loads of space and clutters my text editor area, especially since my text is filled with many equations. So my questions is first if it's possible to keep the live preview when I'm writing the equation and then completely hide it or if that's not possible, completely disable this feature of latex preview?

Comment: Tools > Global Options > R Markdown > Show equation and image previews > Never

Comment: And to set the option only for your file, there's a checkbox `Preview images and equations` when you click the "gear" button (just at the right of the "Knit" button).